# Power apps form: combobox with multiple search fields

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas

What should be a basic functionality in a tool like this has become a nightmare: I have created a power apps screen with a edit form (default mode set to New). This form would be used to enter data in a list, but I'm trying to find a way to help people who use it.
For example, the first field, Client, is searched both by client name and client id.
Now, it's impossible to touch the properties of the components, they have been created automatically and if I modify something it breaks. Also, in there power apps says I can't use functions that create or edit collections  that's great.
So ok I created another combobox inside the form (maybe I can hide the other one and set it automatically) which gets the data from the list, it kinda seems to work, and then re-tried the multiple search fields things, but the fields don't even match. In the properties I see the combo is using "field_1" and "Title" which doesn't even exist in the list, and if I try to put there the fields that I want it says they don't exist.
How do I do this? I tried also an answer where they said to use Filter to search in the list inside the OnChange event, but honestly not much seems to happen.

Maybe it's me, as a programmer maybe I'm not in the mindset of this tool, but I find it's really difficult to do something with it.

Comment: i went with the flow and used the 'fake' field names in searchFields and voilà it somehow works; I get the impression the field names are the standard field names when you create a list (instead of the actual names), so Title is the first, and then field_# for all the others; really well made stuff; now the other impossible problem is how to set the old combo value based on the new one

Comment: ok maybe i did it, i was able to pass the value between the combos using a variable

Comment: i thought i did it... but it doesn't save the item

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are still wrong field names and all, but in the end i made it work; the only step that was missing from what i said in the comments was that i had to set the form in the sharepoint integration component

Comment: except for the little detail where i have to set the [default] mode manually to edit/new, maybe view; i'll see what i can do